# undefined method `home_home_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails development and still trying to understand the building blocks of it. While running this simple code, I am getting following error

```
undefined method `home_home_path'
```

it is coming from this line <%= form_for(@homes) do |f| %> in .html.erb file. Here is my complete code, what I am doing wrong ?

I have Homes Controller file

```
  def index
    @homes = Home.all
  end

  def show
    @home = Home.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @home = Home.new
  end

  def create
    @home = Home.new(params[:home])
    @home.save
  end
```

Homes.rb model file

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :message, :name
end
```

views/homes/index.html.erb

```
# this will show all the data
<% @homes.each do |home| %>
    <%= home.name %><br />
    <%= home.email %> <br />
    <%= home.message %><br />
<% end %>
<br />

# this is a form where you will new records
<%= form_for(@homes) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.text_area :message %>
    <%= f.submit %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use :

```
<%= form_for(@home) do |f| %>
```

(singular)

And if you want to add a form in your index.html , remember to instantiate a new home object in your controller index method :

```
 def index
    @homes = Home.all #For displaying all the homes
    @home = Home.new  #For your form
 end
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. what is the difference between <%= form_for(@home) do |f| %> and <%= form_for(@homes) do |f| %> ? this rails singular and plural is often confusing

Answer (score 1):

`@homes` is an array object.  I'm not really sure how Rails infers the url from this but running

```
url_for Home.limit(2).all
```

will also give you the same error.

The solution is to change @homes to `Home.new` or declare `@home = Home.new` in your controller and use @home in the form.

```
form_for Home.new
```

or

```
# controller
def index
  @homes = Home.all
  @home = Home.new
end

# view
form_for @home
```